# Integration tests Migration from .NET 5 to 6 failed at Mediatr Commands

Tags: c#, integration-testing, .net-5, .net-6.0, mediatr

I am migrating application from .NET 5 to .NET 6 including the integration tests

While running the following command as part of integration tests given an error

```
      // Arrange
        await _mediatr.Send(new MyCommand());
```

> Error constructing handler for request of type MediatR.IRequestHandler`2[MyCommand]. Register your handlers with the container. See the samples in GitHub for examples.

I removed the startup class from api and used only program.cs

What went wrong in my case ?

Adding inner exception also

> Cannot resolve 'MediatR.IRequestHandler`2[Mycommand]' from root provider because it requires scoped service 'Domain.MyDbContext'.

Comment: How do you register your handlers? Also actually  there is no need to change from generic hosting model to the new minimal one during migration.

Comment: @GuruStron 
`code`
services.AddMediatR(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
`code`
This is How I register the handlers at API program.cs file

"Also actually there is no need to change from generic hosting model to the new minimal one durin"g migration. " -> Ya I know But requirement to do that :)

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the inner exception, it seems like the problem lies with the registration of the `Domain.MyDbContext`. Your command handler.requires it to be registered as scoped service.

Comment: But the same works with .Net 5. So then any changes in .NET 6